# Document key usage in Dictionary

Tags: c#, documentation, intellisense, customization

How can I document the key usage in a Dictionary so that it shows in Visual studio when coding using that object?

I'm looking for something like:

```
/// <param name="SpecialName">That Special Name</param>
public Dictionary<string,string> bar;
```

So far the best attempt has been to write my own class:

```
public class SpecialNameDictionary : IDictionary<string, string>
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    /// <param name="specialName">That Special Name</param>
    public string this[string specialName]
    {
        get
        {
            return data[specialName];
        }
    }
}
```

But It adds a lot of code that doesn't do anything. Additionally I must retype every Dictionary method to make it compile.

Is there a better way to achive the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define, dictionary like this:

```
public class SpecialNameDictionary : Dictionary<string, string>
{
    /// <param name="specialName">That Special Name</param>
    public new string this[string specialName]
    {
        get
        {
            return base[specialName];
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of deriving from IDictionary derive from Dictionary, and make new implementation of indexer.

Comment: Thanks! I did try something like that in between my two examples but override didn't work and I forgot the new keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Document the field like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// A map from the special name to the frongulator.
/// </summary>
public Dictionary<string,string> bar;
```

(I assume that in reality it's either not public or not a field - but the same would apply for private fields or public properties.)

You won't get IntelliSense on the indexer itself, but any usage of `bar` should make it reasonably clear.

Three other alternatives:

- Use types which make the usage clearer (a string could be anything, but a `FrongulatorSpecialName` is clearer)
- Make the name of the field/property itself clearer
- Hide the dictionary, but add a method such as "GetFrongulatorBySpecialName"

Answer (score 0):

You could inherit directly from `Dictionary<>` instead of `IDictionary<>`, that way you only need to re-implement the indexer.